# IS .hta files a good choice?

Tags: user-interface, vbscript, hta

so i got to know .hta files, i'm still using them they did really help me creating gui interface for my vbs functions ,but then i knew that Microsoft no longer support hta file so it's most likely not gonna be a part of HTML5. and also it requires IE7 and earlier and removing IE causes serious bugs in my files . ! so .hta is an extension that is gonna appear and disappear in a period of time ,my question is
 
**should i still use .hta coding or i should forget about it already ?**

 i was happy to be able to do what i do in simple lines so knowing that was a sad moment XD what do you think guys ?

**Edit:**yeah hta is still supported in IE11

Comment: I  don't think there's really a question here. You know .hta support is being removed, so continuing to use it is clearly not a good idea. Plain old common sense says that continuing to use a technology you know is dying is a bad idea. Why is there a need to ask  about (or discuss) the decision to stop using it?

Comment: i didn't say it **is** being removed but i said , it **May** be removed because hta is popular today more than ever before , and still getting popular

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues.

VBScript that one day will be removed. It's only still in because large corporations have vbscript timekeeping systems etc and ASP sites use it. There will be no more updates to vbs as it on sustained engineering - 1 programmer to see if any security flaws apply to it. The last programmer (Eric Lippert) to fix a bug took down 10,000 web sites.

If you browse to a local file in IE you get all security advantages of an HTA. So if hta was removed you could rename them to html. And you can open html files in reduced format similar to hta. Plus you can add a web browser control to a form and make your own HTA program.

PS The other day I went looking for a sample hta on my hard drive. All I found was HTA files with object tags. All my script UIs were actually in html files (18 years worth).

Comment: When did I take down 10000 web sites?

Comment: thanks for giving your pure opinion and really doing what this whole website is all about (helping people)